# img src=blob: how to download image?

Tags: python, web-scraping, blob, scrapy

I use Python to download a web-page on Google Art (such as [Portrait of Anthony Valabrègue](https://www.google.com/culturalinstitute/beta/asset/portrait-of-anthony-valabr%C3%A8gue/YQGJT09pbLPLTQ)) which contains images in blobs like:

```
<img src="blob:https://www.google.com/c8c0132a-1ab7-453b-844c-0aab6449af69">
```

How can I download this image? Straightforward downloading using URL `blob:https://www.google.com/c8c0132a-1ab7-453b-844c-0aab6449af69` does not work. The image consists of 6 tiles which are situated in div with XPath

```
$x('//*[@id="yDmH0d"]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[4]/div[11]')
```

Images are stored in `blob`s.

Ideally, I would like to be able to download such kind of images from the webpages using `scrapy` library. I know how to do it for regular urls, but not for `blob:https`.

Yes, there is an easy way to find a regular link to a small-res image on this webpage. But I want to get a higher resolution, that's why I need to download 6 different tiles which are stored in `blob`s.

Comment: I suspect the actual image bits are filled by javascript and not accessible otherwise.

Comment: @9000, Is there a way to make this from python? (may be call some javascript from python). I'm scraping a big website and would like to use `scrapy` library for it.

Comment: Could you post what website are you scraping? usually you can just request `src`  and then just save `response.body` to file.

Comment: @Granitosaurus I updated my answer and give an example of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for your image in the wrong places.
The website you are scraping is filled with javascript clutter which makes it a bit hard to find the image via dom inspect so in this case you need to dig through source page itself.

One place you can find this particular image you are looking for is in the `<meta>` tag:

```
def parse(self, response):
    item = response.xpath('//meta[@property="og:image"]/@content').extract_first()
    #'https://lh5.ggpht.com/-HvgLbwqJ7Yy1iF9imtgsGhVDBDafmvTnDRZSCKl_PNjMT_KXaoNLuO4A7tb4Q'
    yield Request(item, self.parse_image)

def parse_image(self, response):
    with open('image.jpg', 'w') as f:
        f.write(response.body)
```

Comment: Sorry, for not clarifying this before, but I specifically want to **extract 6 tiles and stitch them**, because this will yield a **higher resolution image**. Yes, I have seen that I can find a regular link to a small image.